# Any way to use XML axis properties in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012

Is there any way at all, by using some imports or usings, to use XML axis properties in C#?

I mostly work in VB, and am so used to being able to just query XML with
`(from xel in xdoc.<names>)`

Having to do a little work in C# now, it is annoying to have to write it out verbosely as
`(from xel in xdoc.Elements("names"))`.

It doesn't seem like a big thing, I know, but each element reference this way is 5x as many characters, and so much more verbose. It is a drag to type and read.

If there isn't, I guess I'm at a loss, but hopefully there is some way to use them? Using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: C# doesn't have a direct integration (as VB.NET does) with respect to XML processing/manipulation. Linq to XML is the fastest way to parse documents in C# so far.

Comment: I know like with the `My.` namespace, you can add an import to the VB runtime that will get it for you, so I was hoping maybe there would be some similar approach to include some library that might import it.

Comment: No, it is not about having a library, it's inside VB.NET's language definition but C#'s specification, as of now, doesn't have any feature like that.

Comment: C# does not have the XML Literals feature of VB.NET. This is one area where VB is in advance of C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there isn't.

But there are many ways to process XML with C#. I think LINQ2XML ist the closest to what you're looking for.

- [LINQ2XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb387098.aspx)
- [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (readonly, no caching)
- [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9hbf87%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (read, manipulate, and modify)

Se also [LINQ to XML vs. Other XML Technologies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb387048.aspx), to get an overview.

Comment: Am using LINQ too, in either case. Regardless of using XDocument and it's elements or axis properties, either way I would still query the structure with LINQ. LINQ and jQuery are my favoritest programming libraries right now! B-)